# UILabel detect userName from HTML text and change its font color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdatadetector

I am getting following text from server.

```
"<span class='quill-mention' data-name='@Saurabh Shah
 (5327)' data-id='859155' user-id='859155'>@Saurabh Shah
 (5327)</span>  Test";
```

I want to make it like `@Saurabh Shah` Test

With `@Saurabh Shah` as Blue color font.

Currently I am using following code :

```
        NSMutableAttributedString *attribute = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:
                                            [self.message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

That gives me string : `@Saurabh Shah` Test. But not blue color.

How can i do it?

Comment: The issue is that after converting it, your `NSAttributedString` has only the same attributes for the whole string. There is no difference between "@Saurabh Shah", "(5327)" and "Test".

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I can understand but how can i handle i need to identify range of span and apply  NSForegroundColorAttributeName on that. I have no idea how to achive that

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this in your options:NSForegroundColorAttributeName